# How do I prove that $\max(x,\max(y,z)) = \max(\max(x,y),z))$ using an algebraic formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The maximum of two numbers can be expressed by
$$\max(x,y) = \frac12\left(x+y+|x-y|\right)$$

Consequently, we can write
$$\max(x,\max(y,z))=\frac{1}{4}\left(2x+y+z+|y-z|+|2x-y-z-|y-z||\right)$$
$$\max(\max(x,y),z)=\frac{1}{4}\left(x+y+2z+|x-y|+|-x-y+2z-|x-y||\right)$$
Since we know the values on the left are equal, the expressions on the right should be, too. However, I don't know how to show that those expressions are the same.

Comment: I don't understand the right hand sides, but as for left-hand sides, if you have 3 numbers, isn't it clear what the "maximum" means? It's just the largest of these three numbers (if two or three coincide, it's the larger one). If you want a "formal" proof, consider all 6 options like (1) "$x \leq y \leq z$", (2) "$y \leq x \leq z$", ... etc

Comment: @PeterFranek I get that part, but if the greatest number is same in the both cases then the expression on the right hand sides would've been the same in both of them. It's a different one and I have no idea how to simplify them to a same expression.

Comment: You can easily prove that left-hand sides are equal, maybe via analyzing all the 6 possibilities as I outlined above (after edit). If you want to prove that right-hand sides are equal, **and you know that** the equations are valid, then just compare left hand sides. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: I agree with @PeterFranek. Manipulation of systems of equations involving the absolute value $|x|$ usually requires the distinction of the cases $x<0$ and $x\geq 0.$ In your case, this boils down to the $6$ different cases that represent the different orderings of $x,$ $y$ and $z,$ which you can deal with directly on the left side. You do not gain anything by using the absolute value, it is not simpler than the maximum.

Comment: @PeterFranek Can you please specify what exactly you mean when you say _analyzing all the 6 possibilities_? I wrote down the six possible inequalities along with two cases as mentioned above but don't know how would I go on about analyzing this.

Comment: @Richard If $x\leq y\leq z$, then $\,max(x, \max(y,z))= z = \max(\max(x,y), z)$ etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that you want to work with the right sides, only, and intentionally ignore what you already know about the $\max$ function, you have to make a distinction of $6$ cases. Those $6$ cases must cover each possible order of the numbers $x,$ $y$ and $z.$ Now replace all absolute values $|u|$ with $u$ if $u\geq 0.$ Replace it with $-u$ if $u\leq 0.$ Example:

Case 1: $x\leq y\leq z$
$$
\frac{1}{4}(2x+y+z+|y-z|+|2x-y-z-|y-z||) \\
=\frac{1}{4}(2x+y+z-(y-z)+|2x-y-z+(y-z)|) \\
=\frac{1}{4}(2x+2z+|2x-2z|) \\
=\frac{1}{4}(2x+2z-(2x-2z)) \\
=\frac{1}{4}(4z) \\
=z
$$
In the first step, I used $y\leq z$ and hence $(y-z)\leq 0.$ Therefore, $|y-z|$ must be replaced with $-(y-z).$ In the third step, I used $x\leq z$ which means $2x-2z\leq 0.$

Answer (score 0):

From

$$\max(x,\max(y,z))=\frac{1}{4}\left(2x+y+z+|y-z|+|2x-y-z-|y-z||\right)$$

$$\max(\max(x,y),z)=\frac{1}{4}\left(x+y+2z+|x-y|+|-x-y+2z-|x-y||\right)$$

Let $y-z=a, x-y=b$, so $z=y-a, x=y+b, x-z=a+b$.

Then

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(x+2y+z+b+|a|+|2x-y-z-|y-z||\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(x+2y+z-a+|b|+|-x-y+2z-|x-y||\right)$$

and

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(x+2y+z+b+|a|+|2x-y-z-|a||\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(x+2y+z-a+|b|+|-x-y+2z-|b||\right)$$

and

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(x+2y+z+b+|a|+|a+2b-|a||\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(x+2y+z-a+|b|+|-2a-b-|b||\right)$$

and using $|x|=x, x\gt0, |x|=-x, x\lt0$ we evaluate the last absolute term of the first and second equations independently for the four cases of the signs of $a$ and $b$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\frac{a}{b}&-&+\\
\hline
-&2|a+b|,2|a|&2|b|,2|a|\\
\hline
+&2|a+b|,2|a+b|&2|b|,2|a+b|\\
\hline
\end{array}

with the first entry in a cell being relevant to the first equation, etc..

For example if $a\gt0, b\lt0$ eqn 1 reads

$$|a+2b-|a||=|a+2b-a|=|2b|=2|b|$$

and eqn 2

$$|-2a-b-|b||=|-2a-b+b|=|-2a|=2|a|$$

as $-|b|=b$.

Replacing each last term with the associated cell, the equations match.
If $a,b$ are the same sign, $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$, otherwise they cancel as a whole.

For example $a\lt0,b\gt0$

$$b+|a|+|a+2b-|a||=b+|a|+2|a+b|$$

$$-a+|b|+|-2a-b-|b||=-a+|b|+2|a+b|$$

As  $a\lt0, -a=|a|$ and as $b\gt0, |b|=b$

so we get

$$=b+|a|+2|a+b|$$

$$=|a|+b+2|a+b|$$

which are equal.

Comment: can you dumb down for me what is going on in the table? I can't understand how it's constructed, at all.

Comment: i understand that if i consider all four possible values of $a$ and $b$ i.e. ++,+-,-+,--, then both equation match to same remaining but. I do not understand how you have created the table.